# arduino TFT shield interference with BNO055 (I2C)

Tags: arduino, i2c

my setup:

arduino uno R3
||
seedstudio base SHIELD
||
hiletgo ILI9341 TFT display SHIELD

I2C connector on the base shield <---->  Adafruit BNO055

I am compiling my code WITHOUT #define USE_ADAFRUIT_SHIELD_PINOUT;  meaning it will be using the pinout from the header of the example:

```
// The control pins for the LCD can be assigned to any digital or
// analog pins...but we'll use the analog pins as this allows us to
// double up the pins with the touch screen (see the TFT paint example).
#define LCD_CS A3 // Chip Select goes to Analog 3
#define LCD_CD A2 // Command/Data goes to Analog 2
#define LCD_WR A1 // LCD Write goes to Analog 1
#define LCD_RD A0 // LCD Read goes to Analog 0

#define LCD_RESET A4 // Can alternately just connect to Arduino's reset pin

    // When using the BREAKOUT BOARD only, use these 8 data lines to the LCD:
    // For the Arduino Uno, Duemilanove, Diecimila, etc.:
    //   D0 connects to digital pin 8  (Notice these are
    //   D1 connects to digital pin 9   NOT in order!)
    //   D2 connects to digital pin 2
    //   D3 connects to digital pin 3
    //   D4 connects to digital pin 4
    //   D5 connects to digital pin 5
    //   D6 connects to digital pin 6
    //   D7 connects to digital pin 7
    // For the Arduino Mega, use digital pins 22 through 29
```

Note that A4 and A5 are not in use, so they should be available for the I2C protocol.

basically I want to read something from the BNO and display on the screen.

Screen turns on, BNO turns on.

But soon after the LCD goes blank.  I was able to trace the issue to the following line located in Adafruit_BNO055.cpp:

```
bool Adafruit_BNO055::readLen(adafruit_bno055_reg_t reg, byte *buffer, uint8_t len)
```

which is using _wire calls.

If I empty this function (comment everything out) then the screen remains active (but obviously nothing gets read from BNO055.

Questions:

1. why am I dealing with this interference?
2. assuming I would be able to compile it and run it with #define USE_ADAFRUIT_SHIELD_PINOUT, whould that imply that the screen will be also using I2C, leaving all my Digital and A0-A3 available for other uses?
3. why is my screen which is ILI9341 compatible not running properly using the #define USE_ADAFRUIT_SHIELD_PINOUT declaration? Is HiLetgo incompatible with Adafruit? Different I2C address?

Disregard the plugs connected to the board other than the I2C connection.  I removed those before running this program.

thanks!

Comment: `#define LCD_RESET A4`?

Answer (score 0):

problem solved using the dedicated data interface, leaving the A0--A5 ports available for I2c.  then no more interference